# PDFTron Custom UI -- crops , undo and redo

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, pdftron

Is it possible to customise the ui of crops, undo and redo buttons without touching the java and swift code.
[this is the default crops button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaMtm.png)
[this is the default undo , redo button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wxJy.png)
what im looking for is to create my own buttons and call thoses functions
[perspectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hh7Y.png)
I tried setToolMode, but it works only with tools.
Any suggestions ?

React-native

Comment: Could you elaborate on "customise the ui of crops, undo and redo buttons"? Maybe a mockup will help us understanding what exactly you are looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Thank u so much for ur message, i edited my post so i suppose that is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three APIs can be found in the React-Native project now:

Undo:
https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/master/API.md#undo

Redo:
https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/master/API.md#redo

ShowCrop:
https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-react-native/blob/master/API.md#showcrop

Comment: Can you expand on how these APIs being in the React-Native project addresses the question of how to customize these? Is the point that they can be customized by the parameters exposed via the APIs?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, but the original question asks "im looking for is to create my own buttons and call thoses functions", so basically the API will allow this. It sounds like you are asking something else?

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful resources that you have added. they worked really good as i expected